# Jenkins server run with reverse proxy with google auth

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, jenkins, devops

I have setup jenkins server on aws and provided access to only my org public IP.
I want to open it with my organization vpn for some people working from home so he want access the server. 
Also jenkins have google auth.

how to setup for this problem

Comment: Can you let me know if you are looking to configure Google Auth or you've Configured the Google Auth already and what you wanna know is just about how can you allow the people who are using VPN to access this server?

Comment: For this, all you have to do is, make sure the person who is using VPN to access your Jenkins is Tunnelling to your office's Public IP. If that is the case, then you do not have to do anything else. They should be able to access.